# CSRF prevention in zend framework 1 delete action

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, csrf

When I use Zend_Form for add or edit actions, I add *hash* element for preventing CSRF. But delete forms are so simple (id and submit) that, as I've seen, are often hardcoded in view. I don't think create an independent form for delete action or creating a form like an edit form and removing all visual elements except submit button is a good solution. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a general delete form with hidden id element and a hash csrf element and also captcha and submit elements for delete actions of all models. I thought wrongly that forms need to be related to a particular model directly.

Answer (score 0):

The hash element for csrf can be done via Zend: Zend\Form\Element\Csrf
Forms are not tied to a model, a form can be composed from two models such as Product and Supplier.